Furthest distance from the origin to a point on a circle
Consider the circle with Cartesian equation $(x-2)^2+(y+1)^2=9$.
Find the maximum distance of a point on the circle from the origin.
I can see intuitively that this point must lie on the line that passes through both the origin and the centre of the circle, but I can't make a logical argument as to why.
I can see that the answer must be $(3+\sqrt{5})$ by working with the assumption above.
Can anyone provide either a geometric or algbraic argument for this?

"Can anyone provide either a geometric or algebraic argument for this?" : While this assertion may be accurate, I also have trouble conjuring an intuitive explanation for this.  For what it's worth, I consider this the wrong approach, for this question.  I would set $~f(x) = x^2 + y^2 = 9 - (-4x + 4) - (2y + 1),~$ with $~9 - (y+1)^2 = (x - 2)^2, ~$ and explore the behavior of $~f'(x)~$ and $~f''(x).~$  This should allow you to find the value $~x_0,~$ such that $~ (x_0 - 2)^2 + (y_0 + 1)^2 = 9,~$ and such that $~f(x)~$ is minimized at $~x = x_0.$

Synthetic proof: http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII8.html

Suppose for contradiction that it didn't pass the center C. Say the point furthest from the origin is A. Then the triangle inequality says $D(O,A)\ \leq D(O,C)+D(C,A)=D(O,C) +r$.
But there is a point on the circle such that the distance from the origin is $D(O,C)+r$. It is in fact the point on the line that passes the center.

$(a-2)^2+(b+1)^2=9,\ a^2+b^2\le{M},\ M>0$
$\ a^2+b^2=(a-2)^2+(b+1)^2+4a-2b-5=4+4a-2b$
$(4a-2b)^2\le{(4^2+(-2)^2)(a^2+b^2)}$ (Cauchy–Schwarz inequality)
Thus $a^2+b^2 \le{4+2\sqrt{5M}}$
$\therefore M=4+2\sqrt{5M}$, $\sqrt{M}=3+\sqrt5$

There could be so many approaches.
